# getting error in c++ winmain16 error after setting everything

Tags: c++

im gettuing these error
type here
`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to` WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status``

my code is

```
// Your First C++ Program

#include <iostream>
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You chose the wrong project type.   I do not use g++, but you chose a Windows project instead of a "console" one.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie probably not, gcc just automatically falls back to `winmain` if it can't find `main`

Comment: OP, this is not the file you're compiling. Maybe you didn't save it and end up compiling an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

You're lacking the entry point, also known as the `main` function.

Therefore, the corrected code should look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

You can also try this entry point, but I recommend using `main`, it is an easier method.

```
#include <windows.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE   hInstance,
    HINSTANCE   hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR       lpCmdLine,
    int         nCmdShow
    )
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: MinGW accepts both kinds of `main` regardless of the subsystem selected (gui vs console).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've made some edits.

Comment: The first paragraph is still wrong, you'd get this error regardless of the current subsystem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out as well. I've made some edits. Sorry, I haven't used MinGW GCC/G++ in a looooong time, and even when I was, I wasn't for a long time, so I didn't know that. I appreciate for pointing that out.